# How to reset ng-select in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to reset ng-select when I click on clear button my code is as below:

```
<ng-select (change)="setFilter('','')" 
           [items]="eventType"
           bindLabel="name"
           bindValue="id"
           placeholder="Select Event Type"
           [(ngModel)]="event_type" id="eventType">
</ng-select>
<button class="acq-btn acq-btn-default"(click)="clearFilter()">Clear</button>
```

Function which I've created is as below:

```
eventType = [
    {id: 'create', name: 'Create'},
    {id: 'update', name: 'Update'},
    {id: 'delete', name: 'Delete'},
];

clearFilter(){
    this.event_type = '';
    this.setFilter('','');
}
```

Using select I'm filtering the data. Filtering is working fine.
Clear button is also fine just the UI is showing cross sign like below:

[image]

Can you help me in this issue?

Comment: You can either add an empty option to the `eventType` options or when executing `clearFilter()` you can set a "default" option (should be one of the existing)

Comment: Okay, Do you know how to set default selected value for the same if I go for default value in the eventType array.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using two way binding `[(ngModel)]`:

```
<ng-select 
           (change)="setFilter('','')" 
           [items]="eventType"
           bindLabel="name"
           bindValue="id"
           placeholder="Select Event Type"
           [(ngModel)]="event_type" 
           id="eventType">
</ng-select>
```

In your component it is necessary to add empty value and set `[(ngModel)]` to your desired value in `clearFilter()` method:

```
event_type: any;

eventType = [
    {id: 'empty', name: ''},
    {id: 'create', name: 'Create'},
    {id: 'update', name: 'Update'},
    {id: 'delete', name: 'Delete'},
];

clearFilter(){
    this.event_type = this.eventType[0];
}
```

Comment: @ViewChild('myselect') myselect; this gives an error

Comment: @KunalDholiya ooops, please, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

If, in example, you can set your drop-down to default 'create', you can do it like this:

```
eventType = [
    {id: 'create', name: 'Create'},
    {id: 'update', name: 'Update'},
    {id: 'delete', name: 'Delete'},
];

clearFilter(){
    this.event_type = 'create';
    this.setFilter('','');
}
```

Alternatively you can give a blank option:

```
eventType = [
    {id: '', name: ''},
    {id: 'create', name: 'Create'},
    {id: 'update', name: 'Update'},
    {id: 'delete', name: 'Delete'},
];

clearFilter(){
    this.event_type = '';
    this.setFilter('','');
}
```

Comment: all options will be visible but the selected option will default to `create`, changing the `event_type` will not change the options (which are represented by `eventType`)

Comment: Then it will mislead to the user

Comment: this is what "reset" is all about (resetting/changing the value that was provided by the user), you should define the behavior you want upon reset

Comment: If I display create on reset click then I think it will not give good User experience rather giving create if we can blank it out then It will be more helpful

Comment: so what do you want to display on reset?

Comment: if I can blank it out

Comment: I added an alternate option to my answer for displaying an empty option